# How to speed up feature re-activation?

Tags: powershell, feature-activation, feature-upgrade

Upgrading my solution in production takes forever and I'm looking for ways to improve the typical feature reactivation upgrade scenario.

What actually goes on in the features vary greatly and I'm fully aware that heavy processes within the feature receiver code should be the primary optimization focus (and it is), but I want to know if there are other tricks and suggestions, like shutting down non critical parts (services, caching mechanisms etc) or otherwise preparing SharePoint for the upgrade scenario and service window.

**What can I do - besides optimizing feature code and content - to speed up feature re-activation?**

A typical setup involves reactivating the same features in the same pattern across hundreds of webs. This is done via PowerShell (.Features.Add/Remove)

N.B. - I do not use the feature upgrade functionality - the features has been designed to handle non destructive upgrade/maintenance in the activation receiver event.

Comment: why is it  necessary for you to re-activate the features on every solution update?

Comment: @Gwny That is a valid point - I may be doing unnecessary re-activations of some features. The reason why that happen is at the moment simplicity and certainity: I don't have to worry about which of all the features that contain updates and I don't have to worry about which version of the solution that was in production earlier (design history is a great part of this challenge - I can'jt just switch to the feature upgrade xml declarative approach)